# DAX - How to use condition over a column in GROUPBY

Tags: group-by, powerbi, conditional-statements, dax

I have a measure:

```
VAR calcTable = CALCULATETABLE(
GROUPBY(
'Certification History';
'Certification History'[ID Entity-account];
"Rejections"; SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(); 1)
);
FILTER(
ALLEXCEPT('Certification History'; 'Certification History'[ID Entity-account]; 'Certification History'[Report Date]);
'Certification History'[Status] = "Rejected"
)
)
RETURN
IF(
ISFILTERED('Certification History'[ID Entity-account]);
SUMX(calcTable; [Rejections]);
COUNTROWS(calcTable)
)
```

and I need it to return either SUM or COUNT of 'calcTable'[Rejections] >= {some value}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply a filter on the calculated table, then you can use the filter function on the table:

```
VAR calcTable = 
CALCULATETABLE(GROUPBY('Certification History';
                        'Certification History'[ID Entity-account];
                        "Rejections"; SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(); 1)
                        );
                FILTER(ALLEXCEPT('Certification History'; 'Certification History'[ID Entity-account]; 
                                                          'Certification History'[Report Date]);
                                'Certification History'[Status] = "Rejected"
                    ) 
            )
RETURN IF(ISFILTERED('Certification History'[ID Entity-account]);
          SUMX(FILTER(calcTable;[Rejections]>= {some value}); [Rejections]);
          COUNTROWS(FILTER(calcTable;[Rejections]>= {some value})
          )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect and obvious. Works like charm. Thank You.